# Moving ssl on another server

Tags: windows, ssl

few questions, I am moving to another hosting provider.

1. In IIS, when I create the request CSR, do i have to enter the EXACT same information for it to work with the response certificate I got via email from geotrust?
2. if I have a load balancer, with 2 front end servers, can I install the certificate on both boxes or I have to buy a special certificate for that?

Comment: Are you moving a server, or just content?  Same domain name? If it is the same domain, you can use the existing cert.

Comment: same domain, different server (ISP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not changing your domain name, just [export your certificate and the private key](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737187(WS.10).aspx) from your current server and import it into the new server. (That procedure assumes you're exporting a user certificate. For your web site, choose "Computer Account" when opening the management console snap-in.)

Assuming your load balancer is doing SSL offload you can load your certificate and private key into the load balancer, as well. Export the certificate and private key and import them into your load balancer per the manufacturer's procedure for key import.

Comment: I don't have access to the load balancer, its in a shared enviro.

Comment: Then you don't want the load balancer doing SSL offload, because it'll have your private key. Hopefully the load balancer is SSL-aware and can keep user sessions sticky w/ respect to the given server the SSL session starts on. (Most are, though, so you should be fine). Load the private key and certificate on all your web servers and do SSL on the web servers.

Comment: Also see http://www.sslshopper.com/move-or-copy-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-windows-server-to-another-windows-server.html for clear export/import instructions.